# Read XML value based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML file as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLFILE.xslt"?>
<books>
  <book ISBN="0321173481" author="Michael R. Sweet" >Book1</book>
  <book ISBN="0849371643" author="Gerald Farin" >Book2</book>
  <book ISBN="A558606696" author="David Rogers" >Book3</book>
  <book ISBN="1568810849" author="Gerald Farin" >Book4</book>
</books>
```

I want to get the name of book (book1/book2/book3/book4) based on attribute value (ISBN or author) using XSLT.

Suppose if I write `ISBN = 0321173481` then I should get value : `book1`.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pISBN" select="0321173481"/>
 <xsl:param name="pAuthor" select="'David Rogers'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[@ISBN=$pISBN]"/>
  =====
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[@author=$pAuthor]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the corrected version of your severely malformed pseudo-XML**:

```
<books>
    <book ISBN="0321173481" author="Michael R. Sweet"
    >Book1</book>
    <book ISBN="0849371643" author="Gerald Farin"
    >Book2</book>
    <book ISBN="A558606696" author="David Rogers"
    >Book3</book>
    <book ISBN="1568810849" author="Gerald Farin"
    >Book4</book>
</books>
```

**produces the two wanted and correct results**:

```
  Book1
  =====
  Book3
```

**Do note** that this isn't an XSLT question, but an XPath question.

Answer (score -1):

You can locate the name of a book with a given ISBN as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <!-- find a book with a certain isbn -->
  <xsl:template match="book[@ISBN=0321173481]">
    <!-- output the name -->
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- visit all the documen nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will output a text file with just the name of the selected book. You can of course make the ISBN value of '0321173481', the syntax for passing this in depends on your language.

However, if all you want to do is select the name of a book with a given ISBN, XSLT is not really the best technology, XSLT is designed for transformation of XML documents, not for simple queries.

FOr example you can find the book with a given ISBN using Linq to XML as follows:

```
var name = document.Descendants("book")
                   .Where(book => book.Attribute("ISBN").Value == "2")
                   .Single().Value;
```

Much simpler!

Comment: The transformation you provide doesn't produce any result and seems largely not - focused on the provided XML document. There are no `name` or `isbn` attributes in the provided document. The same applies to your C# code -- there is no "`Name`" in the document.

Comment: Hi, when I answered, the question did not include the XML which was being querries, so I had to guess at the sructure, and gave an example of my guess. i have updated based on the structure provided. My XSLT works and is tested. I would appreciate a +1 again ;-)

Comment: Sigh ... they want to query for ISBN or author. What a silly question!

Comment: If you add a LINQ answer, an XPath answer would also be appropriated.